# Is there any equivalent of mach/mach_time.h library for c++

Tags: c++, objective-c, c++11

I am trying to use some equivalent of this function mach_absolute_time() from the mach/mach_time.h in objective-c but I don't find anything, is there anything similar for c++?

Comment: What does `mach_absolute_time()` do? I don't know objective c but might be able to tell you if you give us more information

Comment: What is your problem by using `mach_absolute_time()` with C++ ?

Comment: @Tribse `mach_absolute_time()` is C function that get the current host time. And I have never had any problem with it in a C++ project ...?

Comment: @Emmanuel ah, didn't know about it being a c function

Comment: @Tribse To be more precise it's a function that come with Mach API on Darwin (OSX/iOS)

Comment: Yes that is the issue, that it is a OSX/iOS library, and my worries are if it will crash when I use it out of a OSX/iOS machines.

Comment: On OSX/iOS, `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` and `std::chromo::steady_clock` are implemented in terms of `mach_absolute_time()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mach_absolute_time()` is a C function that should work fine in C++ code on OS X and iOS. If you need something more portable, try looking up C++11's `std::chrono`.